# clear:both does not work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have below a code snippet where content inside `#FirstDiv` gets appended at runtime which keeps on incrementing.

In Firefox and Chrome, the content of `#SecondDiv` gets shifted downwards when content inside `#FirstDiv` takes extra vertical space on page. However, in IE9 this does not occur, because of which content of `#FirstDiv` and `#SecondDiv` overlaps.

```
 <div id="FirstDiv">html content</div>
 <div id="SecondDiv" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

**Update :-**

I have updated the css for the div1 and div2 at http://jsfiddle.net/msach/Tycwp/1/. Please help.

Comment: Put together a jsFiddle > www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: If the FirstDiv is not floating you don't even need clear: both; on SecondDiv. We need your CSS to be able to make any form of guess as to what your problem might be. Agree that jsFiddle is the way forward if you are to get any help.

Comment: This previous post will surely help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473143/extra-vertical-space-in-ie-after-div-clear

Comment: `clear:both` does work in IE; it's a very well established part of CSS. Maybe it doesn't do what you think it does (it clears floats), or maybe you've got some odd margins or padding interfering, or maybe your page is in quirks mode in IE and getting odd effects from that... but those are guesses without any code. Bottom line is that `clear:both` *does* work in IE, and on its own it can't possibly be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Post your css for floating divs..

Comment: @BenM,AurA,A.k i have pasted the css for both the div at at http://jsfiddle.net/msach/Tycwp/1/. I have spent lot of time but could not figure out whats the issue.

Comment: You've put the CSS, now can you add your HTML, please?

Comment: i have pasted the html there. Just to give you brief i have  Tab1. I keep on adding the tabs like tab1,tab2 etc at run time under 
first div i.e scroller which wraps around when row ends and the second div i.e tab_1 which contains  customerActions etc shiftef towards below.
But it does not happen in IE

Comment: I don't see your HTML in the jsFiddle... Did you definitely press the 'update' button?

Comment: Thanks Ben i found a solution i was missing height:auto in first div.It helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by giving height as auto to upper div

Answer (score 0):

Your second div is not closed

```
 <div id="FirstDiv">html content</div>
 <div id="SecondDiv" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: This is not an issue, OP just mentioned the part of it's HTML not the whole HTML

Comment: @romainberger i have closed the div. Just missed by mistake. Its still an issue