# css clear:both and width 100%?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm not entirely sure where I have got this from but as a rule of habbit if I have a clear div after some floated elements i do the following.

```
<div class='clear'></div>
```

Then in the css

```
.clear{ clear:both; width 100% }
```

For the most part this has seen me through many years as a developer, that is until today.

Today I find out that the 100% width bit was breaking a layout in IE7, removing the width fixed it.

My question is a simple one: **Are there any reasons why a width is required on a clear div?**

Comment: Why do you use empty markup for styling purpose? There's a clean method (originally called easyclearing) also adopted on HTML5Boilerplate that work perfectly everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a better way to clear after floated elements that doesnt require an extra HTML element. As a rule, you want to keep HTML as intuitive and semantic as possible, and leave all design and visual aids to CSS.

If I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="floated-left"></div>
    <div class="floated-right">
</div></div>
<div class="some-non-floating-content"></div>
```

CSS:

```
overflow approach:
.container {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
:after approach:
.container:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both; 
}
```

You can read more about these more semantic approaches here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and here http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.htmls

To answer your specific question about the width, I only know of it being needed when an overflow is applied to ensure the container doesn't collapse.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to replicate what you've suggested. Perhaps you could expand on this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sd27V/1/

Comment: sorry just realized the second link was broken. Here it is: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the :after method. After rereading, I don't think you are able to use this method without a containing div. However, this method provides some benefits over the overflow method, such as cases where the overflow property adds an unneeded scrollbar or hides needed content.  fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sd27V/3/

Comment: I do like the idea of using `:after` with a container div, if you can add that to your answer then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: sure thing, just popped in the css for the :after approach

Answer (score 0):

I always used `clear: both` or only left/right to avoid extra spaces on IE ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473143/extra-vertical-space-in-ie-after-div-clear)).

So, if always worked for me, in all browsers, AFAIK there is no general reason for the `width: 100%`.